# How can I get image data from clipboard in ASP.NET Core 5.0? C# - not with a custom function, just want to save a snipped image to database

Tags: c#, image, .net-core, clipboard

```
public stream ImageData { get; set; }
```

Clipboard.Api not available in .NET Core, only in Windows